# $_GET the variable of javascript to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

my ajax is:

```
add = 'request';
full_val = 'barrack obama';
$.ajax({
        url: 'plugins/add_friend.php',
        data: full_val+'='+add,
        success: function(data)
        {

        }
        });
```

if the javascript variable value changes depending on the conditions, then how will i $_GET[] the variable full_val? I want it to be something like:

```
$_GET[full_val]
```

is there a way to pass the variables of javascript to php?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the literal index `full_val`, then use it in the query string:

```
data: 'full_val='+add,
```

So that in PHP, you'd be able to use `$_GET['full_val']`

Alternatively, you could also put an object in that field:

```
data: {full_val: full_val, add: add},
```

Here is the description:

> **data**
>   Type: *PlainObject* or *String* or *Array* 
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests.

Comment: @monkeycoder sure man no prob, we're all noob when we first time use something :) im glad this helped

Answer (score 1):

Your data just has the `values` and does not have the `keys`. See below for how to pass the `keys` and `values`.

```
add = 'request';
full_val = 'barrack obama';
$.ajax({
    url: 'plugins/add_friend.php',
    data: {full_val:full_val,add:add},
    success: function(data)
    {

    }
});
```

In your PHP use `$_GET['full_val'];`

Answer (score 1):

send your values with data parameter correctly and add `type:get` to define `GET` method

```
add = 'request';
full_val = 'barrack obama';
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: 'plugins/add_friend.php',
  data: {'full_val':full_val,'add':add},
  success: function(data) {

  }
});
```

Then you will get values on php :-

use `$_GET['full_val']` rather `$_GET[full_val]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.get()` method. The variables you can set using an object literal. For example:

```
$.get("/plugins/add_friend.php", {
    add:  "request",
    full: "Barrack Obama"
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log("Status:", data.status);
    console.log("Received:", data.received);
});
```

And the PHP could be done something like this:

```
$add  = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'add', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$full = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'full', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo json_encode(array(
    'status': 'OK',
    'received': "{$add} and {$full}",
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this

```
add = 'request';
full_val = 'barrack obama';
$.ajax({
        url: 'add.php',
        data: 'full_val='+add,
        success: function(data)
        {
           alert(data);
        }
        });
```